# Prolog: maplist (Vars in 1..9) on every elements except for the first row and first column in a matrix. Do not want two predicates

Tags: prolog

I can do this with two predicates, but I want to do it **in a single predicate**.

Details:
Suppose there is a N*N matrix. Except for the first row and first column, only one-digit numbers, i.e. 1 to 9, can fit in.
For example, below is a valid matrix. The image below the matrix shows an invalid one, because the last element is a two digits number.

```
  ____ ____ ____ ____  
 | ** | ** | ** | ** |  
 | ** |  7 |  2 |  1 |
 | ** |  3 |  9 |  5 |
 | ** |  4 |  4 |  7 |
```

invalid matrix example img
[image]

The correct code is:

```
single_digit([_ColHd|Rows]) :-
    maplist(single_digit_, Rows).
single_digit_([_|Contents]) :-
    Contents ins 1..9.
```

I have no idea when merging the two predicates. The incorrect code is:

```
single_digit([_ColHd|Rows]) :-
    maplist((ins 1..9), Rows).
```

Any hints to a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **lambda expression**.

In SWI-Prolog, the lambda expression `[[_|Contents]]>>(Contents ins 1..9)` is `true` if and only if list `Contents` contains only digits.

Thus, you can code your predicate as follows:

```
single_digits([_|Rows]) :- 
    maplist([[_|Contents]]>>(Contents ins 1..9), Rows).

valid_matrix([[*,*,*,*],
              [*,7,2,1],
              [*,3,9,5],
              [*,4,6,7]]).

invalid_matrix([[*,*,*,*],
                [*,7,2,1],
                [*,3,9,5],
                [*,4,6,17]]).
```

Examples:

```
?- valid_matrix(M), single_digit(M).
M = [[*, *, *, *], [*, 7, 2, 1], [*, 3, 9, 5], [*, 4, 6, 7]].

?- invalid_matrix(M), single_digit(M).
false.

?- single_digit([[*,*,*],[*,A,B],[*,C,D]]).
A in 1..9,
B in 1..9,
C in 1..9,
D in 1..9.
```